# Oracle SQL declare given date as variable

Tags: sql, oracle, date, variables, declare

I am trying to declare a variable that represents a date,
my code looks like this:

```
declare
   mydate date;
begin
   select TO_DATE('01.01.2014 00:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') into mydate from dual;
end;

--then comes code like this, the code below works when there is no declaration:
WITH *** AS
(
),

*** AS
(
)

SELECT ***

FROM ***
GROUP BY ***

UNION ALL

SELECT ***
FROM ***

WHERE ***
```

The code above does not work.
Well i am not a pro in SQL so are there any tips?
I also searched trough stackoverflow but did not find an answer.

errorlog (not that helpful):

```
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PLS-00103: found symbol "WITH" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

thanks!

Comment: Please, post the error

Comment: I have a feeling you don't show us the entire code that you are running.

Comment: The code you posted isn't valid SQL. Remove the test code and it will work.

Comment: Well, there is no test code.. but i am not allowed to show all of the code so i just pasted the exact structure with no data in it.. the daclaration at the top of the code is what i need to run because i need to use the variable later in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points:

1. The second select does not have an "INTO". Why do you execute the
   select query in PL/SQL if you  do not use the result.
2. After the "end;" your PL/SQL block has finished. If you want to
   execute another query do not put the end;
3. Why do you use a query to execute a function like to_date? You may
   had done:

> mydate := TO_DATE('01.01.2014','DD.MM.YYYY');

Comment: In my opinion only 3 is valid. 1) The second select is outside PL/SQL. 2) I wonder if that is what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks @borjab opinion 3 looks good but it says "invalid identifier" when i want to use "mydate" like this: "AND a.T_MONAT_M = mydate"

Comment: You need to use the right syntax to sow that you are using a pl/sql variable. 

Use  a.T_MONAT_M = :mydate